# jQuery toggle children list-items

Tags: jquery, html, list

I want to toggle the visibility of single subitems by clicking on the parent list-item.

I have a filetree like this:

```
<div id="browser">
  <ul><li class='folder'>Musik
      <ul><li class='folder'>Alben
        <ul><li class='folder'>100JahreEAV
          <ul>
            <li class='file'>000_erste_allgemeine_verunsicherung_-_100_jahre_eav-backcover.jpg</li>
          <li class='file'>000_erste_allgemeine_verunsicherung_-_100_jahre_eav-frontcover.jpg</li>
          <li class='file'>101_alles_gute_eav.mp3</li><li class='file'>102_popstar.mp3</li>
          <li class='file'>103_samurai.mp3</li><li class='file'>104_kuess_die_hand_schoene_frau.mp3</li>
          <li class='file'>105_coconut_island.mp3</li><li class='file'>106_johnny_i_fahrscheine.mp3</li>
        </ul>
      </li></ul>
    </li></ul>
  </li></ul>
</div>
```

And this is my code so far:

```
$("div#browser ul li ul").hide();
$("li").click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active').children().hide();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active').children().show();
    }
});
```

​
​
The problem is that all parent list-items are affected if I click anywhere. Can you tell me how to toggle just one item at once?

http://jsfiddle.net/g3hWZ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g3hWZ/1/)** — Adding `e.stopPropagation();` prevents the event from propagating to nested elements.

Answer (score 2):

[Stop the propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) of clicks in inner list items.

```
$("li").on("click", function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // rest of your logic here
});
```

When you click on a nested list item, the click event will not travel up the ancestor tree.